# Bundler does not include script file

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2012, ember.js, bundle

I am creating single page app using Ember.js with multiple javascript files, which are combined and minified using bundle feature in VS2012.

If I turn on minification (BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;), ember.js library (ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js) is not included into ember bundle. For clarification filename does NOT end with ".min.js" nor ".debug.js". My bundle definition looks like:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ember").Include(
            "~/Scripts/handlebars-1.0.rc.3.js",
            "~/Scripts/ember-1.0.0-rc.3.js",
            "~/Scripts/ember-i18n.js",
            "~/Scripts/localize/loc-slovak.js"));
```

and it is used on page using:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ember")
```

I have suspicion for too large file (more than 28000 lines, 774 kiB). I tried to update nuget package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization to latest version, but id did not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

.NET's Bundler [breaks Ember RC3](https://github.com/Myslik/csharp-ember-handlebars/issues/15#issuecomment-17117780) if you minify it. It's also breaking Ember-Data. We had to include all Ember related scripts without bundling directly in the `_Layout.cshtml` for now while we work on a different solution (we'll likely include a different transform just for Ember):

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/ember-1.0.0-rc.3.min.js")"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" 
        src="@Url.Content("~/scripts/ember-data.min.js")"></script>
```

If you're using the SPA template([download](http://www.asp.net/single-page-application/overview/templates/emberjs-template) | [source](https://github.com/xqiu/MVCSPAWithEmberjs)), you should be fine as it's still using RC2; but if you update to RC3, then you'll have to modify the bundle config and the layout file according to [this sample](https://github.com/Myslik/csharp-ember-handlebars/tree/master/Ember.Handlebars.ExampleWebAPI).

I didn't have time to send the PR to the SPA template yet, but I have updates for this issue (will do it tonight fo sho)

Another thing if you're using the SPA template: It comes with a HTML helper `@Html.RenderEmber()` to render the templates in the View file in debug mode. This method does not render the template names according to Ember conventions, so I've added another method for now (`@Html.RenderEmberTemplates()`). They should be in sync after the PR/merge.

The sample added in Myslik's repo is probably the most up to date at this point and I suggest that you take a look for reference.

Comment: Well, somehow it's worked since I moved "~/Scripts/ember-i18n.js" and "~/Scripts/localize/loc-slovak.js" to other bundle. But this solution is wonky.

Comment: I know this solution is not ideal. Eventually things will be better for us .NET people :)